# Warum ist in dieser Gedicht-Zeile kein Komma zu setzen?

Tags: comma

Zu den nachstehenden Gedichtzeilen habe ich ein Problem mit der Kommasetzung. In meiner Erstfassung hieß es:

> In blauer Morgenfrühe,
>   Im Grenzland zwischen Traum und Tag,
>   Wird, was ich nicht zu denken wag,
>   Zum Bild mir ohne Mühe.

Jemand hat mich darauf aufmerksam gemacht, dass das Komma hinter „Wird“ falsch ist. Berechtigt wäre das Komma, wenn da stünde:

> Wird das, was ich nicht zu denken wag …

So aber ist das Komma sinnlos. Sinnvoll würde es bei einer anderen Formulierung:

> Formt, was ich nicht zu denken wag,
>   ein Bild sich ohne Mühe.

Dann würde sich der Einschub auf dem ganzen Satz beziehen:

> Ich wage nicht zu denken, dass sich da ohne Mühe ein Bild formt.

Ich halte den Einwand für berechtigt und lasse nun das Komma weg. Kann mir ein Experte erklären, wie ich das nicht nur gefühlsmäßig, sondern mit einer grammatischen Definition erfassen kann?

Comment: Lyrik ist von der korrekten Zeichensetzung befreit ;)

Comment: Es ist gut, dass du deine Frage auf Deutsch stellst, aber dann sollte die Überschrift auch auf Deutsch sein. Ich habe das korrigiert, und habe auch die Formatierung verbessert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versuche, den von dir mit Kommata abgegrenzten Teil des Satzes wegzulassen und du wirst feststellen:

Der Satz hat offensichtlich kein Subjekt mehr.

*was ich nicht zu denken wag'* kann also kein Einschub und auch kein Nebensatz sein, sondern stellt (im Sinne von "etwas") das Subjekt des Satzes dar - Und das wird nicht durch Kommata abgetrennt.

Bei einem Gedicht sind Form, Reim und Rhythmus allerdings wichtiger als korrekte Zeichensetzung - Ich denke, die künstlerische Freiheit siegt hier möglicherweise über die Grammatik und würde es dir durchgehen lassen, trotzdem Kommata zu setzen, wenn du meinst, dass dann die Rhythmik besser wird (und ich finde, es spricht durchaus was dafür).

Answer (score 3):

Jemand hat dich falsch beraten. Die Regel, dass Nebensätze durch Komma abgetrennt werden, gilt unabhängig davon, ob der Nebensatz ein Attribut ist (… wird das, was ich …) oder ein Subjekt (… wird, was ich …).

Diskutieren könnte man über das Komma vor dem Wort *wird.* Mit der originalen Zeichensetzung wird die Phrase «im Grenzland zwischen Traum und Tag» zum Einschub. Man liest also gewissermassen: «In blauer Morgenfrühe (im Grenzland zwischen Traum und Tag) wird, was ich …». Wenn du das Komma weglässt, dann lautet der eigentliche Satz «Im Grenzland zwischen Traum und Tag wird, was ich …», während die Phrase «in blauer Morgenfrühe» eine Art ellipsenhafter Vorschub wird. Die Unterscheidung ist natürlich eher theoretischer Natur.